# How to compute the minimal capabilities' set for a process?

Tags: linux, security, linux-capabilities

What's the best way to compute a **minimal set** of Linux capabilities for any process?

Suppose you're hardening an operating system and some of you tools may require `CAP_NET_ADMIN` and related network privileges while other tools may require `CAP_SYS_NICE`. There should be a way to tell for each executable which capabilities are really required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible approaches to determine required capabilities *at runtime*:

- Subsequently run your program under `strace` without root privileges. Determine which system calls failed with `EPERM` and add corresponding capabilities to your program. Repeat this until all capabilities are gathered.
- Use `SystemTap`, `DTrace` or `Kprobes` to log or
  intercept capability checks in kernel made for your program. (e.g. use `capable` from BCC tools suite as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47991611/3147123))

Unit tests with good coverage will help a lot, I guess. Also note that [capabilities(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities) manual page lists system calls that may require each capability (although it is not a complete list).

**Update:**

The [article](http://www.friedhoff.org/posixfilecaps.html) referenced by @RodrigoBelem mentions `capable_probe` module, which is based on `KProbes`.

Original article with this module was *"POSIX file capabilities: Parceling the power of root"* and it's not availble now (it was hosted [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-posixcap.html)). But you can find the [source code](https://github.com/constanze/GSoC2010_Gentoo_Capabilities/tree/master/capable_probe) and [some docs](https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/Security:Capable_Probe_Module) in the Internet.